# Check if a Data Table has a null value in it

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

What is the best way to check if a Data Set has a null value in it ?

Some t of the time in our scenario, one column will have null values.

I have tried without success this solution :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
reader.Fill(ds);

if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables[0];

    if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(dt.Rows[0]["Rif"]))
    {
        RifNew = dt.Rows[0]["Rif"].ToString(); 
    }
    else
    {
        Rif = "0";
    }
}

return ds;
```

This is the error :

> There is no row at position 0

Comment: The error you are posting has nothing to do with null in a column. It's simply missing rows in the table.. Otherwise your code should be correct i think..

Comment: Your error is due to `dt.Rows[0]`, probaby due to there being no rows

Comment: dt.Rows.Any()  <-- Reference Linq

Comment: @JonasW Ok, thanks it's true int his case I don't have rows... how to do resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way:

```
dataSet.Tables.OfType<DataTable>().Any(x => x.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Any(y => y.ItemArray.Any(z => z == null || z == DBNull.Value)));
```

It checks if any column in any row in any table in a dataset, has a null value.

This code will work in every scenario without any error.

Comment: It returns a bool

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand

Comment: This is how to check if a Data Table has a null value in it